# Oscillators and changing waveforms

Tags: digital-logic, oscillator

I have a 40 MHz crystal oscillator that generates a sine wave. If I use a schmitt trigger on the output, would the output of the schmitt trigger be a 40 MHz square wave, suitable for digital electronics? Will a CMOS type oscillator work with digital electronics?
Oscillator is Abracon ACO-40.000MHZ-EK
Schmitt trigger is CD40106B

Comment: depends on sine Vpp and Logic Vth +/-  50/50% chance of failure without specs

Comment: Which Schmitt trigger? Which CMOS oscillator? Which digital logic family?

Comment: Please provide links to the manufacturer's datasheets (**not** the vendor webpage) for the oscillator and the CD40106B. You also must specify the supply voltage that you intend to use.

Comment: How close to a 50% duty cycle (that is, percentage high time) do you need?  If something really close to 50% is needed, then it might be better to use an 80 MHz crystal, followed by the Schmitt trigger, followed by a toggle flip flop (or some variation thereof).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The datasheet ([ACO-40.000MHZ-EK datasheet)](https://abracon.com/Oscillators/ACO.pdf) indicates the oscillator is not a sine wave one and already outputs CMOS level digital signal suitable for 5v logic.

You don't need a Schmitt trigger buffer.

Answer (score 0):

This answer might be off topic, but when measuring any signal with an oscilloscope be sure the oscilloscope and the oscilloscope probe have a bandwidth spec that is at least 5x the highest frequency you plan to measure. For a 40 MHz logic signal you want to use an oscilloscope and oscilloscope probe whose bandwidth specification is >= 200 MHz. If you don't follow this rule-of-thumb, the oscilloscope or the probe attenuates necessary harmonic content within the signal, which results in a distorted waveform on the oscilloscope's display—i.e., what you see on the oscilloscope display IS NOT a faithful (high fidelity) representation of the actual signal.

TL;DR: Using a low bandwidth oscilloscope or oscilloscope probe to measure your oscillator's output signal will result in a distorted signal that appears as a sine wave and not as a "crisp" 40 MHz digital logic signal.

See also:

- https://www.tek.com/webinar/12-things-consider-when-selecting-your-next-oscilloscope
  (NB: Skip forward in this video to the 5:16 mark)
- https://www.mouser.com/pdfdocs/Tektronix12_things_to_consider1.pdf
  (NB: See slides #'s 5 and 6)
- https://community.keysight.com/community/keysight-blogs/oscilloscopes/blog/2018/02/16/what-is-bandwidth-how-much-do-you-need

Another consideration is loading.  If the oscillator's output signal is connected to a circuit that "loads down"—i.e., that sinks or sources excessive current from—the circuitry in the oscillator's output stage, this overdrives the oscillator's output stage and results in a distorted output signal.